# Python watchdog loops forever on os.system()

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I try to build a throw-away script which automatically compiles my latex document after every change.

The relevant code:

```
class LatexCompiler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent):
            print event
            os.system("pdflatex Thesis.tex")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'

    os.chdir("/path/to/my/tex/file")
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(LatexCompiler(), path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

As soon as I add the os.system(...) line the on_modified() method starts to loop forever after triggering. To ensure that on_modified() is called only once I've omitted the call to os.system() and there it is, just one line got printed describing the event.

So what is going wrong?

Comment: Did you tried to make the "pdflatex Thesis.tex" call with something like the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module? Just mentioning because os.system gets replaced by subprocess

Comment: Yes I did, it made no difference

Comment: What is ``Observer``? What library/module is this?

Comment: watchdog, see: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler `on_modified()` is called whenever *any* existing file in the monitored directory is modified.

I'm guessing, but its likely that `pdflatex` creates intermediate files which it then modifies. Or it could just be that the output pdf file exists from a previous run and is then modified by `pdflatex`. Either way this would trigger the `on_modified()` handler, which in turn runs `pdflatex` again (modifying file(s)), which triggers another call to `on_modified()` .... you get the idea.

You can monitor a specific set of files, your input tex files, and then trigger `pdflatex` only if one of those files is modified. There are some details to clean up, but the following should give you an idea.

```
import os, time, sys
import watchdog.events
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer


class LatexCompiler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, files, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LatexCompiler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._files = files
        print "LatexCompiler(): monitoring files %r" % self._files

    def on_modified(self, event):
        if (isinstance(event, watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent) and
                event.src_path in self._files):
            print event
            os.system("pdflatex %s" % event.src_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'

    observer = Observer()
    files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in ['Thesis.tex', 'Resume.tex']]
    observer.schedule(LatexCompiler(files), path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Comment: Your guess about pdflatex creating intermediate files which trigger on_modified() again and again is correct. Thanks alot for the correct and detailed answer/solution.